# Apple Mach - O Linker Error.No such file or directory Swifty Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i am using cocoapods to install Library `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJson`...Everytime when i compile or run those library are working fine.But when i try to **Archive** it gives me error as below

> Apple Mach - O Linker Error error: no such file or directory:
>   'SwiftyJSON'

Why is this happening,How can i solve this issue?

**UPDATED:**
**i just removed all the pods file from the project and manually imported the library.Still showing the same issue??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's producing error while archiving (and is working for regular run in simulator), check linker flag for release.

Tally linker flag for release and debug.

**If it's different , copy flag from debug to release.**

I had the similar problem with swifty json and alamofire.

Hope this helps.

[image]