# Apple Mach-O Linker Error No Such File or Directory 'UIKit'

Tags: ios, xcode, directory, uikit, linker-errors

I'm getting an Apple-Mach-O Linker Error saying it can't find UIKit. I'm not quite sure as how to proceed. When I delete the contents of my framework search paths it doesn't give the error anymore but of course logically it doesn't find my other frameworks because it needs some framework search paths!

I've also tried cleaning everything and deleting my derived data.

This is the full output:

```
Ld /Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schedule.app/Schedule normal x86_64
cd /Users/Eytan/Desktop/xcodeProjects/iOS/Schedule
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F. -FFrameworks -FQuickSchedule -FSchedule -FSchedule\ WatchKit\ App -FSchedule\ WatchKit\ Extension -FScheduleTests -FSchedule/Images.xcassets -FSchedule\ WatchKit\ App/Images.xcassets -FSchedule\ WatchKit\ Extension/Images.xcassets -FSchedule/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset -FSchedule/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage -FSchedule\ WatchKit\ App/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset -filelist /Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Intermediates/Schedule.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schedule.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Schedule.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Intermediates/Schedule.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schedule.build/Schedule.app.xcent -framework UIKit -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework ParseFacebookUtils -framework ParseUI -framework ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework ParseTwitterUtils -framework Foundation -framework Bolts -framework Parse -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Intermediates/Schedule.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schedule.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Schedule_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Eytan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schedule-dykchbcjtvfkeacentxdqbecmizy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schedule.app/Schedule
```

And this is my current framework search paths for the target that this is happening in:

`$(SRCROOT)   Recursive`

Comment: you can see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264763/apple-mach-o-linker-error-no-such-file-or-directory-swifty-json, it work for me!!! hope this can hope you .

Comment: I just removed all the flags from 'Other Linker Flags', and the error went away!

Answer (score 0):

If it's fixed when you clear your search paths, it's probably missing something that's inherited. In the search path editor, above $(SRCROOT), add $(inherited). Does that help?

Comment: Adding it does not affect the problem.